# How can delete Main.storyboard file in macOS storyboard project and not using it?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, storyboard

I am following an article which tells me to find main interface and make some edit on it, but I am unable to find it, here is a screen shot of it:

[image]

So my Xcode version is Version 14.1 (14B47b) and I looked for it in General but did not found it, so where is it in new version? I am working on macOS storyboard project.

As you could see the article says that I should delete my Main.storyboard because we are going to build this app programmatically so I did delete that file but Xcode makes error of:

> Thread 1: "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

I am totally ok with deleting Main.storyboard because i am not going to touch it but when I delete it makes that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to remove the reference of Main.storyboard to launch at the beginning

1. Remove reference from Launch Screen File
   [image]
2. Remove reference from Info.plist
   [image]

After this you need to setup the window with root view in application delegate.